# Java graph library with List of objects instead of hash tables

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, jgrapht

I've tried JGraphT It looks very promising but my problem is that my objects are changing and I want the Graph to map objects as a `List` not through hash table. So is there any other library? or what I should do to overcome that ?

Comment: How about JUNG 2.0 Framework? It is more or less like JGraphT. A few examples use key map to store nodes and edges to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JGraphT is free you can download the source code and modify it to use a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of the default hash table.

Comment: well, I don't think i'm with the experience that would allow me to do that